# $v-e+f=2-2g$ as a topological invariant

Tags: general-topology, polyhedra

Euler's theorem was expanded to encompass polyhedrons homeomorphic to not only spheres but also $g$-holed toruses. I've tried to understand proofs about how $2-2g$ is a topological invariant but have always had trouble with the use of planar graphs.

Can anyone explain how $2-2g$ is a topological invariant without using the concept of planar graphs?

Comment: In general you will need embeddings of graphs such that faces are homeomorphic to disks - but for the sphere this precisely boils down to the concept of planar graph.

Answer (score 0):

$2g-2$ is a topological invariant of any closed orientable surface $S$ of genus $g$, namely its [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic). There are several ways to see that the Euler characteristic is a topological invariant, see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074078/is-euler-characteristic-the-only-topological-invariant-that-is-linear-in-numbers), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828482/intuitive-reason-why-the-euler-characteristic-is-an-alternating-sum?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the building tiles like the ones in the image below; you will be using planar graphs, but you will (hopefully) think about them differently, and maybe that helps:

[image]

If you use these to build a closed surface (i.e. every single edge has exactly two tiles meeting along it), you can count

- How many corners where two or more edges meet, $v$
- How many edges there are where two tiles meet, $e$
- How many tiles you used, $f$
- How many holes your surface has, $g$

and you will find that $v-e+f = 2-2g$

For instance, if you use triangular tiles to make an icosahedron, you have

- 12 corners
- 30 edges
- 20 tiles
- 0 holes

and we can confirm that $12-30+20 = 2+2\cdot0$.

You can also use them to make a figure like this:

[image: Square torus]

You will get

- 32 corners
- 64 edges
- 32 tiles
- 1 hole

and we can confirm that $32 - 64 + 32 = 2-2\cdot 1$.

In general, you can use tiles like this which are bent and crooked (as long as the tiles themselves do not have any holes) to make any closed surface, and the result stays the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still a little confused about the second structure(hole-in-a-cube) though. If I were to not think of it as being made up from separate blocks and think of it as drilling a cube-hole out of a cube, wouldn't it be 16 vertices, 24 edges, and 10 faces? Thus ending up as 16-24+10=2 just like the Euler number of a structure homeomorphic to a sphere when this one seems homeomorphic to a torus.What I'm thinking of is something like this (https://marketplace.secondlife.com/p/T-3D-Creations-Hole-Cube-MESH-Full-Perm/3701211?id=3701211&slug=T-3D-Creations-Hole-Cube-MESH-Full-Perm)

Comment: @RoxaneMin It's **important** that faces do not have holes in them. So you will have to divide the top and bottom faces into at least two (holeless) faces each, with a resulting increase in the number of edges (and possibly vertices, depending on where exactly you divide them).

Comment: Then in the same sense if I were to calculate for a structure with a small cube and a bigger cube stuck by a face, would I have to divide the top face of the bigger cube so that that face doesn't have a hole in the middle?

Comment: @RoxaneMin Yes, you would have to do that. Note, however, that this is topology. We allow faces to _not be flat_, so the entire "side of the big cube with the small cube stuck to it" can be a single face if you want, making the count of faces, edges and vertices identical to that of a regular cube.